# How to calculate the date when the sum of entries exceeded the threshold?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Let's assume there is a table:

| day | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 30 |

I want to know when turnover reached 30, in case above it's happened on 2 day. How to query this in SQL? I guess I have to use window function but dont' know which one exactly

Comment: You will **never** be able to convert day 2 to a [date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#:~:text=1%20microsecond-,date,-4%20bytes)  (because of missing info like month and year)

Answer (score 2):

You could get running Total and then put filter and limit the record with LIMIT 1 or you could use MIN for the day:

```
WITH cumulative_sum_table AS (
  SELECT day, amount, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY day) AS running_total
  FROM your_table
)
SELECT day
FROM cumulative_sum_table
WHERE running_total >= 30
ORDER BY day
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The logic is good, but `top` is not a thing in Postgres, use `limit` of `fetch` instead.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting, I had checked in sql-server on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it via aggregation

```
select yt.day
from yourtable yt
join yourtable y2
on yt2.day <= yt
group by day
having SUM(yt2.amount) >= 30
limit 0, 1;
```